# AvailableFreeSpace return no space but space exists

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

i have this functions for get available free space on device.

```
public static Boolean IsAvailableFreeSpace(long size)
    {
        long availableFreeSpace = (long)0;
        using (IsolatedStorageFile userStoreForApplication = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            availableFreeSpace = userStoreForApplication.AvailableFreeSpace;
        }
        return ((long) availableFreeSpace < (long)size) ? false : true;
    }
```

in a main of my project i have a "global" variable boolean and I'll see if I have more than 10 MB(52428800 byte)

```
  Booelan AvailableFreeSpace = IsAvaiabileFreeSpace(52428800);
```

in a particular device users have a 10/12GB free space and my function returns FALSE!! 
Why?

Comment: What is the value of `userStoreForApplication.AvailableFreeSpace` - have you debuged it?

Comment: the problem occurs on some users' devices. in my tests it never occurred

Comment: Maybe you can try it other way - by properties - [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445993/how-i-can-find-out-the-avaible-free-space-in-a-universal-windows-phone-8-1-app/23446870#23446870).

Comment: this method works with app developer with wp 8.0? i receive "The method or operation is not implemented"

Comment: You are right, they will work only under WP8.1