# How to get logical drives names in Windows 10?

Tags: uwp

In WPF, we can access the drives names using GetLogicalDrives() method in System.IO namespace. But for UWP, GetLogicalDrives() method is not in System.IO namespace. So how can I access drives names in windows 10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of all physical drives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175414/list-of-all-physical-drives)

Comment: That link does not have a answer for how to get drive info in Windows 10. If you know, please tell me

Comment: The link says that you cannot do that - at least from what I know.

Comment: When you need such PC specific info then maybe UWP is not the best platform.

Answer (score 1):

Nor sure if this answers your question, but:

```
var removableDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
var folders = await removableDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
```

This will return a collection you can iterate through:

```
foreach (StorageFolder folder in folders)
{
  sb.AppendFormat("DisplayName: {0}", folder.DisplayName);
}
```

So for a USB stick called "ESD-USB" this will return the name of the drive you see in Explorer along with the drive letter, e.g: `"ESD-USB (D:)"`.

`KnownFolders` is in the `Windows.Storage` namespace.

**Manifest: Update for question in comments**

It's a while since I did any work on this, so not sure if this is all you need to do.  Here's the relevant manifest info:

Under **Capabilities** I have the following ticked: Removable Storage, Pictures Library, Music Library, Videos Library, Internet (Client).

Comment: this gives an unathorize exception.  Please elaborate on how to set up the manifest to get around this error.