# UWP How to get StorageDevice freespace and capacity?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

in my UWP app I use this construction to get list of all StorageDevices:

```
List<StorageFolder> list = new List<StorageFolder>();
var selector = Windows.Devices.Portable.StorageDevice.GetDeviceSelector();

var devices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

foreach (Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation device in devices)
    {
        // Get device root folder
        StorageFolder rootFolder = Windows.Devices.Portable.StorageDevice.FromId(device.Id);
        list.Add(rootFolder);
    }

RemovableItems.DataContext = new RemovableStorageViewModel(list);
```

How to get freespace and capacity of this devices? 
I try to get it from folder props `rootFolder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new List<string>())`, but this props is missing.

**UPDATE:**

Available props values:
[image: Available props values]

Available props keys:
[image: Available props keys]

Why freespace and capacity is missing?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23446870/2681948) may help little.

Comment: @Romasz nope. I know how to get this props from standard folder, but in my case it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried without success to do the same thing. Microsoft has omitted those properties for some reason. Hoping that the next SDK update will address this.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to query for `System.FreeSpace` and `System.Capacity` property (more about available property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760719%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

Usage:

```
var retrivedProperties = await rootFolder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { "System.FreeSpace" });
var freeSpace = (UInt64)retrivedProperties["System.FreeSpace"];
```

Comment: Yes, I try it. I cant get `System.FreeSpace` and `System.Capacity` props coz they are missing.

Comment: retrivedProperties["System.FreeSpace"] cant found.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to retrieve the "System.FreeSpace" and "System.Capacity" properties for **some** drives as of Windows 10, version 1803 (10.0: Build 17134), using the answer by thang2410199

You can see a code sample in my answer to this question: [Error while accessing AvailableFreeSpace/TotalSize in DriveInfo in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252751/error-while-accessing-availablefreespace-totalsize-in-driveinfo-in-uwp/52357145#52357145)