# UWP Windows.Devices.Portable cannot be referenced

Tags: c#, uwp, portability, mtp

In my UWP app I'm trying to get an access to **Portable Devices** (MTP,PTP) storage.

In the following question the OP used the namespace **Windows.Devices.Portable** without problems. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482256/uwp-how-to-get-storagedevice-freespace-and-capacity).

But in my case:
[image]

**Windows.Devices** contains no **Portable** class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. The namespace **Windows.Devices.Portable** lives in the **Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP**.

So, all you need to do is to reference the extension.

Comment: Yes because why wouldn't the Portable namespace be in the Desktop extensions :)