# Getting the available free space programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile

How do i get the available free space in Universal Windows Phone 10 programmatically, as `AvailableFreeSpace` property does not exist in UWP 10

```
public long GetFreeSize()
{
    using (var isolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        var sizeInBytes = isolatedStorageFile.AvailableFreeSpace;//this AvailableFreeSpace proprrty doesnt exist in uwp
        var sizeInKB = sizeInBytes / 1024.0;
        var sizeInMB = sizeInKB / 1024.0;
        var sizeInGB = sizeInMB / 1024.0;
    }

    return (long)0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482256/uwp-how-to-get-storagedevice-freespace-and-capacity

Comment: welcome to SO, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Take a look at the answer from post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445993/how-i-can-find-out-the-avaible-free-space-in-a-universal-windows-phone-8-1-app

Comment: I have tried both possible options from the suggested post but it doesnot work for UWP 10. @AVK Naidu