# Get information about logical drives (UWP, C#, Windows)

Tags: c#, uwp

I am creating a UWP app (C#, Windows, Visual Studio 2019).
I want to list the available space, total space and total free space of the logical drives (for example, the drives are C, D, E).
In order to do this, I have used DLLs that contain `GetDiskFreeSpaceExA`. I tried 2 things: DllImport with kernel32.dll and DllImport with a DLL file that I have created.

1. Firstly, I have called this function using kernel32.dll

   ```
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

   static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(String drivePath,
                                         out ULARGE_INTEGER availableBytes,
                                         out ULARGE_INTEGER totalBytes,
                                         out ULARGE_INTEGER totalFreeBytes);
   ```
2. Secondly, I have created a C DLL using Windows Desktop Wizard and added it to the UWP app. The name of the DLL file is GetMemory.dll. The function `GetSpaceData` calls `GetDiskFreeSpaceExA`

   [DllImport("GetMemory.dll", EntryPoint = "GetSpaceData", CallingConvention =  CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

   internal static extern int GetSpaceData(string drivePath,
   out ULARGE_INTEGER availableBytes,
   out ULARGE_INTEGER totalBytes,
   out ULARGE_INTEGER totalFreeBytes);

This is the C file used to create the DLL file:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int GetSpaceData(char* path, 
                                       ULARGE_INTEGER *ulFreeForUser, 
                                       ULARGE_INTEGER *ulTotal,
                                       ULARGE_INTEGER *ulFree)
{
        if (GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(path, ulFreeForUser, ulTotal, ulFree))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

In both cases, I can only access the data about C drive (I have to access space data about E and D drives, too): the result from the functions is true and != 0 for "C:" and false and == 0 for "D:" and "E:".

I have also tried to access them using the C# code in UWP, but failed.
Getting the storage data about the logical drives, using dlls and `GetDiskFreeSpaceExA`, in a C# Console App works.

Why can I only access the data about C drive (UWP)? How can I access the data for all of the logical drives (UWP)?

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], post an [mcve] and [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: How did you define `ULARGE_INTEGER`?  That shouldn’t be valid in a p/Invoke definition.

Comment: I used `Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop?view=visualstudiosdk-2019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability in **Package.appxmanifest.**
In addition, broadFileSystemAccess is a restricted capability. You need to configure in **Settings > Privacy > File system.**

Then please refer to the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252751/error-while-accessing-availablefreespace-totalsize-in-driveinfo-in-uwp/52357145#52357145), the description of this solution as follows:

1. Call [DriveInfo.GetDrives()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=net-5.0) to retrieve the drive names of all logical
   drives on a computer.
2. Traverse all Drives and use [StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderfrompathasync?view=winrt-19041)
   to    get the root folder of each disk.
3. Get the specified properties through
   [StorageItemContentProperties.RetrievePropertiesAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.retrievepropertiesasync?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Storage_FileProperties_StorageItemContentProperties_RetrievePropertiesAsync_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterable_System_String__).